# Have to analyze two statements about group actions and determine which of them is true.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I have two statements about group actions and have to determine which of them are true and why.

The question goes as follows:

> Let $X$ be a set and $G$ a group with $g \in G$. Let $\alpha_g $ be an action of the group $G$ in the set $X$. Determine which of the following is true.
>
> I) If $\alpha_g(x_1) = \alpha_g(x_2)$, then $x_1 = x_2$.
>
> II) If $\alpha_{g_1}(x) = \alpha_{g_2}(x)$, then $g_1 = g_2$.

I've got a hunch that statement II may be false, but cannot determine why.

I verified the core properties of group actions and searched for some examples but couldn't find none that matched any of these statements.

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: What work have you done on this? For example, have you looked at various examples of simple group actions to test the truth of these statements? You might want to take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with an emphasis on how to [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: You say you have "searched for some examples ..." Well why not have a look at all the actions of a group of order $2$ on a set of size $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For I, recall that a group action is a homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut} S$ where $\operatorname{Aut} S$ denotes the group of bijections from $S$ to itself, given by $g \mapsto \alpha_g$. Hence $\alpha_g$ is injective. (If this is not your definition of a group action, it is a good exercise to show that $\alpha_g$ is a bijection.)

For II, consider the trivial action $g \mapsto \text{Id}_S$.

Comment: To my knowledge, $Aut(S)$ denotes the group of the automophisms of $S$, which is then sensibile if $S$ is a group, only. Rather, the group of all the bijections on the set $S$ is usually denoted with $Sym(S)$. This being said, the substance of your answer is correct.